# cant find LatLng import in android studio

Tags: java, android, import

When i try to use LatLng class in my code, there is no import available. could anyone please solve the problem? i've installed google play services module thriugh SDK manager also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its available in

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.0'

You can replace the version with the latest one available.

Answer (score 5):

LatLng is in the `com.google.android.gms.maps.model package`, which you can use if you add `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'` to gradle dependencies.

Comment: it says failed to find:com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0

Comment: @ShanWave007 add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` to build.gradle(project) buildscript dependencies, and add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to the bottom of build.gradle(app)

Comment: it says unable to load class 'com.google.gson.JsonObject'

Comment: that is unrelated to this question. Just google how to import gson

Answer (score 2):

include this into your app **build.gradle** file

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

...

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
}
```

for more information take a look to [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)